# mod_rewrite - How do I check the HTTP_REFERER's QUERY_STRING?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a redirect rule that says "If the `HTTP_REFERER` contains a certain `QUERY_STRING`, do this..."

In other words, I have this scenario:

```
HTTP_REFERER: http://www.example.com/admin.php?foo=bar
```

... and I would like to say, "If the `HTTP_REFERER` contains the `QUERY_STRING` 'foo=bar', do this..." Make sense? Lol

Maybe it's not even possible? I'm relatively new to mod_rewrite.

Comment: If you work out your own solution, just post it as an answer. Don't delete a good resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the `QUERY_STRING` is already a part of the `HTTP_REFERER`.

So the solution is simple:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !foo=bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^[^?]+\?([^&]*&)*foo=bar(&.*)?$
```